# computeVertexNormals

Tags: three.js

I am using 3d modifiers https://github.com/foo123/MOD3 to bend a cube. After the geometry is updated (vertex positions are changed) the lights are not updated, the cube is still shaded as if nothing changed.
So I tried

`cube.geometry.computeVertexNormals()`

and

`cube.geometry.computeFaceNormals()`

but after that the cube is not rendered like a cube anymore but like an "ugly sphere":

[image]

On the left is shading after `computeVertexNormals()`, on the right is the original shading.

How can I update the shading after the geometry changes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use MOD3 to modify just the geometry, then you are going to have to update the normals yourself.

```
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Each new vertex normal will be the normalized sum of the face normals of the neighboring faces that share that vertex.

If you don't like the way that three.js does it, your only choice is to modify the vertex normals yourself.

three.js r.85

Comment: Even if I don't modify the geometry, if I do                 geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals(); the result will be the same as in the screenshot (left side). What I don't understant is how the normals are initially correct but after geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals(); they are "ugly sphere" style

Comment: I understand the problem now.      computeVertexNormals()      method does not inspect if a face is on a flat surface, it always calculates average values. If we have a cube geometry 1x1x1 , it will be shaded like a sphere becasue vertex normals would be averages instead of face normal.

Comment: Exactly. Just as I explained. Remember to "accept" this answer by clicking on the check mark.