# how to Smooth .obj in Three.js

Tags: three.js, .obj

Is there any way to smooth an .OBJ in three.js ? I already load the model but it looks faceted

I already use the shading: THREE.SmoothShading, in the material but doesn't affect it

```
var Loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
Loader.load('models/stockcarchasisc.obj', function(carGeo, materials) {   

// var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
var map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "models/st_tex.jpg" );
map.wrapS = map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; // This set/place UV coordinates at 0 ! 
var material2 = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ 
color: 0xa65e00,
side: THREE.DoubleSide,
map: map,    
});
carGeo.traverse( function(child) {
if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

// apply custom material
child.material = material2;
// enable casting shadows
child.castShadow = true;
child.receiveShadow = true;
}
});
carGeo.position.y = 25;
carGeo.scale.set(25, 25, 25);
var helper = new THREE.VertexNormalsHelper( carGeo, 5, 0x00ff00, 5 );
scene.add(carGeo);
scene.add(helper);
});
```

Comment: does the model have vertex normals?

Comment: It should ! Is theres any way to know it for sure?

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=helper#Reference/Helpers/VertexNormalsHelper

Comment: I paste my code in the original question, already add the helper but I don't see any normals

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13234832/1980846

Comment: Where should I put these two lines?

geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();

Comment: before `carGeo.traverse`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable smooth shading with Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749446/enable-smooth-shading-with-three-js)