# Enable smooth shading with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm rendering an object with textures using MTL and OBJ files with Three.js. My code here works but my model is displayed as flat shaded. How do I enable smooth shading?

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();  
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath('assets/');
mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('assets/');
mtlLoader.load('asset.mtl', function(materials) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.setPath('assets/');
    objLoader.load('asset.obj', function(object) {

       //
       // This solved my problem
       //
       object.traverse(function(child) {
           if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
           {
              child.material.shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
           }
       });
       //
       //

       scene.add(object);
    });
});
```

EDIT:
I updated my code with a solution that fixed my problem based on the accepted answer.

Comment: most probably: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202480/three-js-calculating-vertex-normals

Comment: I had tried that one already but it doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: Have you taken a look in asset.mtl ? Maybe it is set in there somewhere

Comment: can you post an image of what you are rendering?

Comment: Does the shading look "flat" or "faceted"? Better if you share a screenshot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be one of two things that I can think of right now.

It could be that the material is set to `FlatShading`. In this case just somehow retrieve the object and use `object.material.shading = THREE.SmoothShading;` to fix.

If that doesn't change it, it's possible that the object contains per-vertex-normals (meaning that every vertex of every triangle has a normal attached to it) and that all normals for each triangle point in the same direction. This is something that should better be solved in the 3d-editing process, but you can also re-compute the normals in three.js:

```
object.geometry.computeVertexNormals(true);
```

This should *[1]* recompute the normals for smooth surfaces. However, it will only work for regular Geometries and Indexed BufferGeometries (or, to put it the other way around: it won't work if the geometry doesn't have information about vertices being reused for adjacent faces)

*[1]: I didn't test it myself and just go after what I just read in the code*

Answer (score 0):

You may need to smooth geometry as follows:

```
geometry = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices(geometry, 0.1);
geometry.computeVertexNormals(true);
```