# Three.js imported obj smoothing issues

Tags: three.js, blender

Anyone seen anything like this when importing a .obj file into three.js? Trying to get to the bottom of why i am getting the weird polygons all over the place (renders fine in blender etc.) there are no modifiers on the surfaces. Feeling is this a UV/Normals issue, been so long since I have used three.js, am a bit lost, thanks for any pointers...

[image: Bad render]

Comment: Do you have proper face side orientation? (Blender CTL+N)

Comment: Can you please share your OBJ file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable smooth shading with Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749446/enable-smooth-shading-with-three-js)

Comment: Also related: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/wrong-normals-when-loading-draco-models/2007/4

Comment: I suspect it is overlapping vertices that need to be welded/merged. Sharing the .obj will allow us to help more